# how to take operator from command line argument in c?

Tags: c

I have been asked in one of my Assignment to Write a program to make commandline Addition?

Format like that :

```
excutablefile firstoperand opertator secondoperand
```

Example:

```
./a.out          1          +          3
```

result : 4

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int a,b,c;
    a=atoi(argv[1]);
    b=atoi(argv[3]);
    c=a atoi(argv[2]) b;
    printf("%d",c);
    return 0; 
}
```

When I compile it, I get this error:

```
embedded@Embedded-boo-N5010:~$ cc command.c 
command.c: In function ‘main’:
command.c:7:8: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘atoi’
c=a atoi(argv[2]) b;
    ^
```

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: Look at the line with the error again... The compiler is even helpful enough to point out *where* on the line you should look.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i observed so many time buts could not understand.

Comment: Learn to understand the errors. Every good programmer does.

Comment: @Bathsheba sir i have written the code for all the arithmetic operation but only addition and subtraction is working it it not working for multiplication and division..

Comment: I suggest you ask another question specifically aimed at the multiplication and division. In doing this, only paste up *relevant* code.

Answer (score 1):

`c=a atoi(argv[2]) b;` is not syntactically valid. Your compiler is being helpful here; do learn to read the errors carefully.

You *could* use `strcmp` to compare this argument value with `"+"`, `"-"` etc.

```
if (!strcmp("+", argv[2])){
    // plus operator
    c = a + b;
} else {/*ToDo - other operators*/

}
```

Also, don't forget to check the *size* of `argv` before accessing elements. That's what `argc` gives you.

Comment: no i didnt mean c=atoi(argv[2]);

Comment: i have to add two values by giving the inputs and operator from command line

Comment: @embbeded what's wrong with that answer ?

Comment: Thank you sir it worked..Thank you so much

Comment: @MichaelWalz i got the answer :)